# Why doesn't this batch file work for me?

Tags: batch-file

The following batch file is not woking.
`@echo off
python -c "print('echo text')" > %TEMP%\test.bat
call %TEMP%\test.bat`

Can anyone help me with this?.
**edit:**
I needed unix eval functionality in windows. I could not find a direct way though.
So I redirected the eval string to a temporary batch file and executed it. The temporary batch file was successfully created but calling it did not work in the above case.
I noticed that any command after the `test.bat` creation did not work.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? We need specifics.

Comment: Do you get an error message? try putting pause at the end of the file so you can see what the cmd window is saying.

Comment: I voted to close/move, you may be better off asking on StackOverflow, since this is (sort of) a programming question. If others agree it will be moved automagically.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the %TEMP%\ directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "python" you are calling is a batch file (python.bat in the path perhaps?) then the launching batch file will abort after calling it, unless you use the Call command like you are doing for temp.bat.

So perhaps 
`@echo off
call python -c "print('echo text')" > %TEMP%\test.bat
call %TEMP%\test.bat`
will give you better mileage?